# Building and printing complex table layouts with Java

Tags: java, layout, printing, graphics

A customer requested me a software, and one of its requirements is build a form and fill it with data collected from database.

This form is currently being created in Excel. It uses cells to build the form, some cells have blank background, others blank background with black bottom  border (to look like a line where text is typed), others have gray background with white text, and there's also a logo image. In Excel, some cells are merged to become bigger than other cells. They fill the text in another spreadsheet and the required cells in the form take that text and format it.

I've looked many report frameworks in Java, some are very complex and some look like Excel's graph builders, but I saw none that can make a complex 2D form like this.

Data filled in it is simple, like name, quantity, some numbers, but they have different length requiring for example that name's cell to be merged to cover a full horizontal line, and some have smaller font size. There's no repeated data that would require sorting and I have no problem gathering the data.

In the end, the filled form must also be printed, so I can't use normal Swing table or grid. It will be used in Windows now, but it'd be nice to support Linux printing too.

Any suggestion of a Java component that builds a 2D layout like this and fills it with strings will be very much appreciated. I even thought of taking a screenshot of their current form and just use 2D Graphics to print the text, but I'd not be able to print it.

This is an example of the kind of form I must build, it's somewhat like that but some areas have gray background with white text:

[image]

No, it's not a duplicate, but it is a good example of the layout.

Comment: You might want to try using Crystal Reports, it seems more suited for something like this.

Comment: I can build a PDF, but it needs to be printed on paper. So I'd rather print it directly from my software than build a PDF and open it in a PDF reader just to be printed. They don't need to be stored digitally.

Comment: Thanks David, but Crystal Reports seems too expensive to pay for. But I've found JasperReports, I'm gonna take a look on it to see if it's able to do what I need.